# How do I Restart a shutdown embeddedKafkaServer in a Spring Unit Test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have a Spring-boot Unit Test that is testing Switch Back capabilities of my application when the primary Kafka Cluster comes online.

The application successfully switches to secondary when the primary goes offline. Now we're adding the ability to switch back to primary on a timer instead of failure.

My Test Method Looks like so:

```
   //Rochelle = Primary BootStrapServers
   //Hudson   = Secondary BootStrapServers


   @Test
   public void send_switchback() throws Exception
   {
      //Get ABSwitchCluster to check failover details
      KafkaSwitchCluster ktSwitch = (KafkaSwitchCluster)
              ((BootStrapExposerProducerFactory)
                       kafkaTemplate.getProducerFactory()).getBootStrapSupplier();

      assertThat(ktSwitch,             notNullValue());
      assertThat(ktSwitch.get(),       is(Rochelle));
      assertThat(ktSwitch.isPrimary(), is(true));

      assertThat(getBootStrapServersList(), is(Rochelle));

      log.info("Shutdown Broker to test Failover.");

      //Shutdown Primary Servers to simulate disconnection
      shutdownBroker_primary();
      //Allow for fail over to happen
      if ( ktSwitch.isPrimary() )
      {
         try
         {
            synchronized (lock)
            {  //pause to give Idle Event a chance to fire
               for (int i = 0; i <= timeOut && ktSwitch.isPrimary(); ++i)
               //while ( ktSwitch.isPrimary() )
               {  //poll for cluster switch
                  lock.wait(Duration.ofSeconds(15).toMillis());
               }
            }
         }
         catch (InterruptedException IGNORE)
         { fail("Unable to wait for cluster switch. " + IGNORE.getMessage()); }
      }

      //Confirm Failover has happened
      assertThat(ktSwitch.get(),            is(Hudson));
      assertThat(ktSwitch.isPrimary(),      is(false));
      assertThat(getBootStrapServersList(), is(Hudson));

      assertThat(kafkaSwitchCluster.get(),       is(Hudson));
      assertThat(kafkaSwitchCluster.isPrimary(), is(false));

      //Send a message on backup server
      String message = "Test Failover";
      send(message);

      String msg = records.poll(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      assertThat(msg, notNullValue());
      assertThat(msg, is(message));

      startup_primary();
      //embeddedKafkaRule.getEmbeddedKafka();

      assertThat(embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString(), is(Rochelle));
      String brokers = embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString();

      if ( !kafkaProducerErrorHandler.areBrokersUp(brokers) )
      {
         synchronized (lock)
         {
            for ( int i=0;
                  i <= 15 && !kafkaProducerErrorHandler.areBrokersUp(brokers)
                  && registry.isRunning();
                  ++i )
            { lock.wait(Duration.ofSeconds(1).toMillis()); }
         }
      }

      //TODO: test Scheduled Fire
      kafkaProducerErrorHandler.primarySwitch();

      if ( !kafkaSwitchCluster.isPrimary() )
      {
         try
         {
            synchronized (lock)
            {  //pause to give Idle Event a chance to fire
               for (int i = 0; i <= timeOut && !kafkaSwitchCluster.isPrimary(); ++i)
               //while ( !ktSwitch.isPrimary() )
               {  //poll for cluster switch
                  lock.wait(Duration.ofSeconds(15).toMillis());
               }
            }
         }
         catch (InterruptedException IGNORE)
         { fail("Unable to wait for cluster switch. " + IGNORE.getMessage()); }
      }

      assertThat(brokers,              anyOf(is(Rochelle), is(Hudson))); //port didn't change
      assertThat(brokers,              is(Rochelle)); //is primary
      assertThat(kafkaSwitchCluster.isPrimary(), is(true));
      //assertThat(ktSwitch.isPrimary(), is(true));
      assertThat(ktSwitch.get(),       is(brokers));

      assertThat(kafkaProducerErrorHandler.areBrokersUp(brokers),  is(true));
      assertThat(kafkaProducerErrorHandler.areBrokersUp(Rochelle), is(true));

      assertThat(ktSwitch.isPrimary(), is(true));
      //assertThat(ktSwitch.get(),       not(anyOf(is(Hudson), is(Rochelle))));
      assertThat(ktSwitch.get(),       is(embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString()));

      //Send a message on backup server
      message = "Test newPrimary";
      send(message);

      msg = records.poll(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      assertThat(msg, notNullValue());
      assertThat(msg, is(message));

      log.info("Test is finished");
   }
```

I'm using this method to shutdown my Primary Embedded Kafka

```
   public void shutdownBroker_primary()
   {
      for(KafkaServer ks : embeddedKafka.getKafkaServers())
      { ks.shutdown(); }
      for(KafkaServer ks : embeddedKafka.getKafkaServers())
      { ks.awaitShutdown(); }
   }
```

I'm using this to restart Kafka:

```
public void startup_primary()
   {
      //registry.stop();
      //kafkaSwitchCluster.Rochelle = embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString();
      for(KafkaServer ks : embeddedKafka.getKafkaServers()) { ks.startup(); }
      registry.start();
   }
```

`primarySwitch()` is a Scheduled event to switch the cluster back to primary. It is Directly called in test.  It's a wrapper around the same code that switches the in-use cluster when Kafka goes down.

How do I get the Primary Embedded Kafka Cluster to successfully start after I shut it down so I can prove that the application can successfully move back to the primary cluster once It's available again?

---

**UPDATE:**
I have created Code Example on Github with what I have so far: https://github.com/raystorm/Kafka-Example .

---

**UPDATE: 2** the [Linked Repository Above](https://github.com/raystorm/Kafka-Example) has been updated based on the accepted answer below, and now all tests pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't really designed for this use case, but the following works, as long as you don't need to retain data between the broker instances...

```java
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka(topics = "so64145670", bootstrapServersProperty = "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers")
class So64145670ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private EmbeddedKafkaBroker broker;

    @Test
    void restartBroker(@Autowired KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) throws Exception {
        SendResult<String, String> sendResult = template.send("so64145670", "foo").get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("+++" + sendResult.getRecordMetadata());
        this.broker.destroy();
        // restart
        this.broker.afterPropertiesSet();
        sendResult = template.send("so64145670", "bar").get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("+++" + sendResult.getRecordMetadata());
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

Here's one with two brokers...

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = { So64145670Application.class, So64145670ApplicationTests.Config.class })
@EmbeddedKafka(topics = "so64145670", bootstrapServersProperty = "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers")
class So64145670ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka;

    @Autowired
    private EmbeddedKafkaBroker secondBroker;

    @Test
    void restartBroker(@Autowired KafkaTemplate<String, String> template,
            @Autowired ProducerFactory<String, String> pf) throws Exception {

        SendResult<String, String> sendResult = template.send("so64145670", "foo").get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("+++" + sendResult.getRecordMetadata());
        KafkaTemplate<String, String> secondTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(pf,
                Map.of(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, this.secondBroker.getBrokersAsString()));
        sendResult = secondTemplate.send("so64145670-1", "foo").get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("+++" + sendResult.getRecordMetadata());
        this.embeddedKafka.destroy();
        this.secondBroker.destroy();
        // restart
        this.embeddedKafka.afterPropertiesSet();
        this.secondBroker.afterPropertiesSet();
        sendResult = template.send("so64145670", "bar").get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("+++" + sendResult.getRecordMetadata());
        sendResult = secondTemplate.send("so64145670-1", "bar").get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("+++" + sendResult.getRecordMetadata());
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class Config {

        @Bean
        EmbeddedKafkaBroker secondBroker() {
            return new EmbeddedKafkaBroker(1, true, "so64145670-1")
                    .brokerListProperty("spring.kafka.second.server");
        }

    }

}
```

```
+++so64145670-1@0
+++so64145670-1-0@0
+++so64145670-1@0
+++so64145670-1-0@0
```

Comment: `afterPropertiesSet()` throws an Exception for me.  
`KafkaException: Socket server failed to bind to localhost:50674: Address already in use.`

Comment: Something's not right, `destroy` will shut down the old server and wait for the completion; if you are still manually calling `shutdown()`, you need to also call `awaitShutdown` (and also shut down the embedded zookeeper server) - it's easier to just call `destroy()`.

Comment: Removed both `shutdown()` and `awaitShutdown()` in favor of `destroy()`. same Exception.   But my test is running 2 embedded brokers. `embeddedKafka` and `embeddedKafka_secondary` could they be interfering with each other somehow?

Comment: Nothing that I can think of; if you can provide a small, complete, stripped-down example, I can take a look.

Comment: You have 3 brokers - 2 `@ClassRule`s and one `@EmbeddedKafka` - which adds a bean to the test context. You should use Spring beans or class rules; not both - remove the `@EmbeddedKafka` or simply add the second broker as a `@Bean`. It's not entirely clear why that would cause the address already in use; you should end up with 3 different ports, but let's see what happens when you clean that up. Also, in future, please avoid using Lombok when posting examples - it's a pain for those of us that don't use it to get started with looking at what the sample is doing.

Comment: Stack Trace after removing the annotated broker.  I've tried a few different things, but cannot figure out what it needs to properly load the application context.
https://gist.github.com/raystorm/616c845f904422c8c310d39a30ec5a4c

Comment: You are relying on the annotated broker to set that property; it would be better to remove the `@ClassRule`s and add the second broker as a `@Bean` to the test context.

Comment: I've tried a few different iterations, of Switching to annotation based. Here's a stacktrace of the Bean Creation Exception where it can't find the value for 'spring.kafka.embedded.brokers` https://gist.github.com/raystorm/ff692f55450ab40169e45dc200fa9c68

Comment: I updated my example to use 2 embedded brokers; it works as expected.

Comment: I had to do some additional work. But I was able to get a working solution based on your feedback thank you.   I updated my Github Repo Example with a version of it.